# How to retrieve all the data from the Left Table while using Group by on 2nd table with Having Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, outer-join

Consider three tables,

1. Team
2. Members (Each member belongs to some team)
3. Tasks (each task is performed by some member)

**Tasks Table**

```
t_id      member_id
1       1
2       1 
3       2
4       1
```

**Members Table**

```
id      name      team_id
1       Ali       1
2       Khalil    1
3       Bilal     1
4       John      2
5       Smith     2
```

Now the result I want is the **complete details of the Members Table of A PARTICULAR TEAM along with the Number of Total Tasks each member has performed.**

To solve this, I wrote this query,

```
select m.*, count(t.member_id) as 'Tasks' 
from tbl_member m 
left join tbl_task t on m.m_id = t.member_id 
group by t.member_id 
having m.team_id = :team_id
```

where team_id can be any variable given by the user.

When I run this query for team_id = 1, I get these results (only printing Member Names and his total tasks)

```
m_name     Tasks
    Ali     3
    Khalil  1
```

As you can see, it skips **Bilal** who is also part of Team_ID = 1 but because he has performed **0 Tasks**, it doesn't print Bilal (even though I used **left join**)

Similarly, if I use Team_ID = 2, I get these reuslts,

```
  m_name     Tasks
    John     0
```

It now prints John (who has done 0 Tasks) but it doesn't print **Smith** who also is part of Team 2 but has not done any task.

So, basically, the query is missing all those people who have done 0 tasks (unless all team members have done 0 tasks. In such a case, it only prints the first member of that team and skips the other, like in the case of Team ID = 2)

Can anyone please tell me how do I fix this? I want to print all the members of one team along with their count, even if their total task count is zero. *Please note that it is not compulsory that this must be done using Joins. This can also be done with Subqueries but again, I couldn't make the right logic with subqueries either.*

Comment: You may group only tbl_task then join. You may use correlated subquery in the output list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use subquery to get the number of task done without any left join or group by clause.

DB-Fiddle:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table tbl_task(t_id int,      member_id int);
 insert into tbl_task values(1,       1);
 insert into tbl_task values(2,       1); 
 insert into tbl_task values(3,       2);
 insert into tbl_task values(4,       1);

 create table tbl_member(id int, name varchar(100),      team_id int);
 insert into tbl_member values(1,       'Ali'       ,1);
 insert into tbl_member values(2,       'Khalil'    ,1);
 insert into tbl_member values(3,       'Bilal'     ,1);
 insert into tbl_member values(4,       'John'      ,2);
 insert into tbl_member values(5,       'Smith'     ,2);
```

Query:

```
 select m.*,(select count(t_id)from tbl_task t where t.member_id=m.id)  as 'Tasks' 
 from tbl_member m 
 where m.team_id=1
```

Ouput:

| id | name | team_id | Tasks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ali | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | Khalil | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Bilal | 1 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c06ab99d56962d7b916d6ce03cb48a1)*

Answer (score 3):

Your `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` are undoing the `LEFT JOIN`.  Try this:

```
select m.*, count(t.member_id) as Tasks
from tbl_member m left join
     tbl_task t
     on m.m_id = t.member_id and
        m.team_id = :team_id
group by m.m_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Group by the left table columns, `m.id` ..

```
select m.*, count(t.member_id) as 'Tasks' 
from tbl_member m 
left join tbl_task t on m.id = t.member_id 
where m.team_id = :team_id
group by m.id, m.name, m.team_id
```

I'm using column names from your table definitions. Your query uses different naming. Correct it as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Gordon's answer is, of course, correct.  There's another approach you might take however. It involves this subquery to count the tasks.

```
        select member_id, count(*) numb
          from tbl_task
         group by member_id
```

Then you left join that to your members table.

```js
select m.*, t.numb as 'Tasks' 
 from tbl_member m 
 left join (  select member_id, count(*) numb
                 from tbl_task
                group by member_id
           ) t on m.m_id = t.member_id 
 where m.team_id = :team_id
```

This query pattern uses the `main LEFT JOIN aggregate` pattern, where the `aggregate` table contains either zero or one row corresponding to the `main` table.  You may get some NULL values from team members who haven't done any tasks. You can fix that with COALESCE().

```js
select m.*, COALESCE(t.numb, 0) as 'Tasks'
```

I wrote this up because I find the  `main LEFT JOIN aggregate` pattern very useful for various report queries.  For example, you might need this to get aggregates by member from two different tables. If you don't use the pattern you'll get a combinatorial explosion and high numbers.  Here's an example counting absences as well as tasks.

```js
select m.*, t.numb as 'Tasks', a.numb as 'Absences'
 from tbl_member m 
 left join (  select member_id, count(*) numb
                 from tbl_task
                group by member_id
           ) t on m.m_id = t.member_id 
 left join (  select member_id, count(*) numb
                 from tbl_absence
                group by member_id
           ) a on m.m_id = t.member_id 
 where m.team_id = :team_id
```

Your original query didn't work correctly because you can convert a LEFT JOIN into an ordinary JOIN by mentioning columns from the second table in WHERE or HAVING clauses. That's because both `NULL = value` and `NULL <> value` *always* is false, so any WHERE criterion except `WHERE (col IS NULL OR col = val)` will not be met.

Comment: "mentioning columns from the second table in WHERE or HAVING clauses" in a way excluding NULLs, to be precise.